# Is there a way to sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{y}{n} - \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{y}{n} \right)\right]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm interested in computing the sum for $y>0$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[ \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{y}{n} \right) - \frac{y}{n} \right]
$$

In formula (42.1.6) of Hansen's A Table of Series and Products, there is a formula:
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty\\(n\neq0)}^{\infty}\left[ \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{y}{n+x} \right) - \frac{y}{n} \right] \ = \ \tan^{-1}\big( \tanh(\pi y) \cot(\pi x) \big) - \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{y}{x} \right)
$$

In taking $x \to 0^{+}$, the above formula becomes the following:
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty\\(n\neq0)}^{\infty}\left[ \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{y}{n} \right) - \frac{y}{n} \right] \ = \ 0
$$

Which simplifies to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[ -\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{y}{n} \right) + \frac{y}{n} \right] + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[ \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{y}{n} \right) - \frac{y}{n} \right] = 0$, which is obvious.

Is there a way to sum this series?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{\arctan\pars{y \over n} - {y \over n}}}}  =
-\int_{0}^{y}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{x^{2} \over n\pars{n^{2} + x^{2}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,\Im\int_{0}^{y}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{x \over n\pars{n - \ic x}}\,\dd x =
-\,\Im\int_{0}^{y}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{x \over \pars{n + 1}\pars{n + 1 - \ic x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,\Im\int_{0}^{y}
x\,{\Psi\pars{1} - \Psi\pars{1 - \ic x} \over \ic x}\,\dd x\qquad
\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}
\\[5mm] = &\
\Re\int_{0}^{y}
\bracks{-\gamma - \Psi\pars{1 - \ic x}}\,\dd x\qquad
\pars{~\gamma:\ Euler\!-\!Mascheroni\ Constant~}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\gamma\, y - \Re\bracks{\ic\,\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{1 - \ic y}}} =
\bbx{-\gamma\, y + \Im\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{1 - \ic y}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Hi Felix my friend.   This is very similar to how I did this (and deleted after I saw your post).  But I don't believe that the closed form we obtained is more useful than the original series for numerical computation.

Comment: @MarkViola Hi, Mark my friend. I saw your answer and it's right. That's true: The involved $\Gamma$ will require a numerical evaluation as the original post.

Answer (score 2):

By the inverse Laplace transform, assuming $y\in(0,1)$,

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\arctan\frac{y}{n}-\frac{y}{n}\right)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(-y+\frac{\sin(sy)}{s}\right)\frac{ds}{e^s-1}$$
and the RHS can be represented as
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n y^{2n+1} \zeta(2n+1)}{(2n+1)}\tag{"odd" series}$$
which, on the other hand, does not simplify nicely like the similar
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n y^{2n}\zeta(2n)}{2n} = \log\sqrt{\frac{\pi y}{\sinh(\pi y)}}\tag{"even" series}.$$
Indeed the "even" series is related to $\text{Re} \log\Gamma(1+iy)$ which simplifies thanks to the reflection formula, while your series is given by the "odd" series, related to $\text{Im}\log\Gamma(1+iy)$. For values of $y$ close to zero a numerical approximation by series acceleration is pretty simple; for very large values of $y$ Stirling's approximation is recommended.

Comment: I am quite interested how the last equation is obtained. Could you please provide some related references?

Comment: @Szeto: the $\log\Gamma$ function is involved and $\Gamma(1-is)\Gamma(is)$ simplifies by the reflection formula.

Comment: When $y = 1$, the result is $\approx -0.2756$ but your result yields $\approx -0.6509$.

Comment: How did you use the ILT to arrive at the first equation?

Comment: @FelixMarin: the series involving $\zeta(2n+1)$ returns the correct outcome, the second series is shown just for providing a similar example.

Comment: @MarkViola: $$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\arctan\frac{y}{z} = \frac{\sin(sy)}{s} $$ i.e. $\arctan\frac{y}{n} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(sy)}{s} e^{-ns}\,ds.$

Comment: $0$ k. Sorry. I guess I didn't read carefully your answer.

Comment: Jack, why not just use the series representation for the arctangent, interchange the order of summation and quickly arrive at the "odd series?"  That seems a bit more direct than to use the LT representation.

Comment: @MarkViola: indeed, that is a shortcut for $y\in(-1,1)$. What we really gain through the (inverse) Laplace transform is that the analytic continuation of the odd series (related to $\text{Im}\log\Gamma$) continues to match the value of the original series also for $|y|>1$.